# Subgroup of finite field is invariant under Frobenius map

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, cyclic-groups

Let $q$ be a prime power and $a\in\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$. Let $m$ be a positive integer dividing $q+1 $ and $H \subset\Bbb{F}_{q^2}^{\times}$ a subgroup of order $m(q-1)$.

If $a \in H \cup \{0\}$, why is $a^m$ invariant under the Frobenius map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of units of a finite field of order $q^2$ is cyclic of order $q^2-1=(q-1)(q+1)$. In particular it has a *unique* subgroup $H$ of order $m(q-1)$. Then the $m$-th powers in $H$ form a subgroup of index $m$ in $H$, so this is the unique subgroup of order $q-1$ in the full unit group, which is of course $\Bbb{F}_q^{\times}$.

Comment: That's all there is to it :-)

Comment: Thanks for this very nice answer! I've got one last question to this: Why has the equation $x^q +x = a^m$ all its roots in $F_{q^2}$ ?

Comment: @JohnD For every $\beta\in\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$ you have$$(\beta^q+\beta)^q=\beta^{q^2}+\beta^q=\beta^q+\beta,$$
which shows that $\beta^q+\beta\in\Bbb{F}_q$. That is to say, each $\beta\in\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$ is a root of $x^q+x-c$ for some $c\in\Bbb{F}_q$. There are precisely $|\Bbb{F}_q|=q$ such polynomials with at most $q$ roots each, for a total of at most $q^2$ distinct roots for these polynomials altogether. As each of the $q^2$ elements of $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$ is a root of such a polynomial, we see that each has precisely $q$ roots in $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$. That is, each has all its roots in $\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$.